# Docker error encountered when creating web service

Tags: docker, service, connectivity

ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

```
Docker-compose up -d --build
```

[image]

```
Docker ps
```

[image]

------------- Docker-compose.yml -----------------
version: "3"

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    container_name: 'web'
    env_file: ./docker/php/.env
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - mssql
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./docker/logs/apache2:/var/log/apache2
      - ./docker/logs/php:/var/log/php
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=local.dev.com"

mssql:
    build: ./docker/mssql
    container_name: 'mssql'
    env_file: ./docker/mssql/.env
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data/mssql:/var/opt/mssql

Comment: `docker` commands generally write out text to the console, not images; can you replace these images with the actual text of these outputs, and include enough source code (like your `docker-compose.yml` file) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Thanks for your comment David.Creating web   ... error

ERROR: for web  Cannot start service php: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.

ERROR: for php  Cannot start service php: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

Comment: docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: ./docker/php
    container_name: 'web'
    env_file: ./docker/php/.env
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - mssql
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/config/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ./docker/config/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./docker/logs/apache2:/var/log/apache2
      - ./docker/logs/php:/var/log/php
    environment:
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=local.dev.com"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your port `80` isn't already in use.

Also, [here's a thread](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/573) with several possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your response Scott. 
I checked the thread that you have provided. But no luck. Yes, port 80 is currently occupied.  Is there any other way to resolve this? Thanks